# What type do I create a property of a struct in Rust for a field that in my database is Point?

Tags: rust, mariadb, rust-rocket, rust-sqlx

I am new to rust and I don't have much experience, what I am trying is to create a new row in my database in which the table is the following from a MariaDB database

[image]

and for that he planned to use a structure like the following

```rust
#[derive(sqlx::FromRow, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Bar {
    pub id: Option<i32>,
    pub name: Option<String>,
    pub description: Option<String>,
    pub address: Option<String>,
    pub create_At: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
    pub update: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
    pub schedule: Option<String>,
    pub capacitance_idcapacitance: Option<i32>,
    // pub coors
}
```

And my question is, what type did the Coors field create? Or how could I save this information in the database?

Comment: [Doesn't look like this is supported yet](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/2735). A quick look at the documentation shows it can be done [manually](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/trait.FromRow.html#manual-implementation). My guess is that you'll have to implement `Decode` for [`MySqlValue`](https://docs.rs/sqlx-mysql/0.7.2/sqlx_mysql/struct.MySqlValue.html) somehow.

Comment: Since this is a `sqlx` question, rather than a Rust question, you'll have better luck getting advice [from sqlx themselves](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx) rather than here. You'll be lucky if an expert finds this question.

Comment: @JMAA Thank you for your comments, I am very new to the language and I literally do not understand the reason for many things, where should I place the "decode" sorry for my stupid question

Comment: I you are new to the language, read [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/). Then you will be in a better place to understand the documentation I linked you to. `Decode` is a trait that I think you need to implement (if you don't know what that means, read The Book), but check the `sqlx` documentation for the details. I can't help you if you can't read the documentation.